# Blocking access to the Neo4j web admin interface

Tags: neo4j

I was wondering if there is any other way apart from having apache+mod_proxy to block access to the neo4j webadmin interface alone ?

Setting org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0. allows external connection ( which is desired so that my other applications can talk to the server ) but this allows access to the webadmin interface to anyone who has the URL.

Any suggestions on blocking webadmin alone is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply custom security rules as documented on http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html#_server_authorization_rules. If your `SecurityRule` implementation uses `/webadmin/*` for the `forURIPath()` method, it's fairly easy to block access.